# About validation in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I got problem in validation with modal popup. This is my `index.html.haml`:

```
.container-index
  %h1 All Posts Here
  %button.btn.btn-info(type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal") New Post

  = render 'form'
  - @posts.each do |post|
    .col-md-4
      %h3= link_to post.title,post
      %p= post.content
      = "#{time_ago_in_words post.created_at} ago "
```

`_form.html.haml`:

```
.container
  = simple_form_for current_user.posts.build do |f|
    %div.modal.fade#myModal(tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel")
      %div.modal-dialog(role="document")
        %div.modal-content
          %div.modal-header
            %button.close(type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close")
              %span(aria-hidden="true") ×
            %h3.modal-title#myModalLabel New Post

          %div.modal-body
            = f.input :title, label:"Title",class:'form-group',name: 'title'
            = f.input :content, label:'Content',class:'form-group',name:'content'

          %div.modal-footer
            %button.btn.btn-danger#mynewpostclose(type="button" data-dismiss="modal") Close
            = f.submit 'Create', class:"btn btn-primary"
```

`post.rb`:

```
validates :title, presence: true
validates :content, presence: true
```

`posts_controller.rb`:

```
 
before_action :find_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")
  end

  def new
    @post = current_user.posts.build
  end

  def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
    if @post.save
      redirect_to @post, notice: 'Created Successfully'
    else
      render 'new'
    end

  end

  def show
  end

  def edit

  end

  def update
    if @post.update(post_params)
      redirect_to @post, notice: 'Updated Successfully'
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    redirect_to posts_path(@post), notice: 'Deleted Successfully'
  end

  private

  def find_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content)
  end
```

I do not know how to show up the warning
When I create a new post without any title or content
it'll link to a blank page and don't create any new post
I just wanna call warning inside modal when submit, anyone can help me,plzz?

Comment: I think you should use JavaScript  in `simple_form_for .... remote: true` and in JS you will be able add errors

Comment: Will you clearly more a litle bit,plzz? I'd never use this way before

Answer (score 0):

In your form you need to replace this line

```
= simple_form_for current_user.posts.build do |f|
```

with this;

```
= simple_form_for @post do |f|
```

This way, when your create action renders the `new` template, the form will be given the instance of Post which failed to save allowing simple form to display the error messages.

Comment: I tried but then it show an error: "undefined method `model_name' for nil:NilClass". Any advices for me?

Comment: What does your new.html.haml view look like?

Comment: = link_to 'Home', root_path, class: 'btn btn-info'

%h1 New Post
= render 'form'
I don't know how to write comment like you

Comment: OK, my last suggestion is to try replacing it with this line instead:

`= simple_form_for [current_user, @post] do |f|`

Comment: didn't work too, the only run is this:  = simple_form_for current_user.post.build do |f| .